# how to catch method type (generick type) at runtime

Tags: java, generics

I have to do some catching of type at runtime. I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Tricky place is that this type is generic.

***Code*** snippet:

```
public class Ship<T> {

    private ArrayList<T> passangers = new ArrayList<T>();

    public Ship(ArrayList<T> passangers) {
        this.passangers = passangers;
    }

    public void addPassanger(T object) {
        passangers.add(object);
    }
    // ... rest of class
}
```

How to catch which type is into method `addPassanger(T object)` at runtime.
Catch this type of `T`.

**Update:**

I follow [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight) suggestions.

And added into main():

```
    Ship<Droid> victoria = new Ship<Droid>(new ArrayList<Droid>(), Droid.class);

    victoria.addPassanger(new Droid("Christofor Columb"));
    victoria.addPassanger(new Droid("Fernando Magelan"));
    victoria.addPassanger(new Droid("James Kuk"));

    System.out.print("Passengers type is:");
    victoria.getPassengerType();
    System.out.println();
    victoria.showPassangers();
```

But output is next:

```
Passengers type is:
At the sheep are presented:
1 Christofor Columb
2 Fernando Magelan
3 James Kuk
```

Here line:

> victoria.getPassengerType();

which should return class type return nothing.

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: Why do you need to know the type?

Comment: object.getClass() can do this, but it won't necessarily return the type defined in the code itself, which gets erased at compilation type. Anyway, you may have a design flaw. Try avoiding specific types checking for determining your flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of type erasure, by run-time the type information is gone. The common trick here is to store the `Class` of `T` in the constructor, like this:

```
public class Ship<T> {

    private final Class<T> passengerType;
    private ArrayList<T> passengers = new ArrayList<T>();

    public Sheep(ArrayList<T> passengers, Class<T> passengerType) {
        this.passengers = passengers;
        this.passengerType = passengerType;
    }

    public void addPassenger(T object) {
        passengers.add(object);
    }
    // ... rest of class
}
```

Comment: I tried to call this new constructor `Ship<Droid> victoria = new Ship<Droid>(new ArrayList<Droid>(), Droid.class);` and when `getPassengerType()` is calling it return nothing?

Comment: @nazar_art This probably means that you mistyped `passengerType` in the header of the constructor, so `this.passengerType = passengerType` is an assignment of the field to itself. Set breakpoint at the end of the constructor, and check that `this.passengerType` has been assigned.